# SMTP Host Configuration

Tags: java, smtp

we are configuring email server in our application with own mail server but while sending mail i got this exception.

```
  host = "mail.xxx.com"
  port = 25
  username = "xx@xx.com"
  password = "xx"
  props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
            "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"25",
            "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
            "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]

 org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.co-optimum.com, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.co-optimum.com, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?; message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.co-optimum.com, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection
```

?

Comment: Add code snippet and provide complete error stack trace

Comment: host = "mail.xxx.com"
   port = 25
   username = "xx@xx.com"
   password = "xx"
   props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
      "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"25",
    "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
    "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]

Comment: Are you sure that you can telent to `mail.co-optimum.com` on port no. 25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top three reasons that i've seen this happen is due to the following:

1. The TCP port is blocked on the application server due to security policy
2. The TCP port is blocked by firewall or other network device due to security policy
3. The target SMTP server requires you to "whitelist" your application server to allow the connection.

All three cases happens because a company wants to prevent spammers from using their email server has spam delivery systems.

Talk with your support personnel.

hope that helps...

Comment: I am able to connect in telnet

Answer (score 0):

From the Exception, it seems that the server does not work on 25.

Try to send mail by telnet firstly to make sure the mail server works well.

- if the domain of mailfrom is not mail server domain

  1. the domain of rcptto is not mail server domain,

     the mail server should deny it, because it can be generate many spam mail.
  2. the domain of rcptto is mail server domain,

     no problem
- the domain of mailfrom is mail server domain,

  you must do auth-login (I think it is your problem).

If you use javamail, props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); and create   session with Authenticator.

Comment: I am able to connect in telnet in application level i am getting the same problem. please give me the solution if possible.

Comment: for MAIL FROM: works fine but for RCPT TO:  got 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay problem

Comment: - if the domain of mailfrom is not mail server domain
      1. the domain of rcptto is not mail server domain,
           the mail server should deny it, because it can be generate many spam mail.
      2. the domain of rcptto is mail server domain,
           no problem
- the domain of mailfrom is mail server domain,
      you must do auth-login (I think it is your problem)